# Why node.js asynchronous is not timeout?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

## First(solved)

I am try promise of node.js.

```js
function testpromise(data, ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (data=="hello") {
            setTimeout(resolve(data), ms);
            return;
        }
        reject("emm");
    })
}

testpromise("123", 3000)
    .then((res) => { console.log(res) })
    .catch((err) => { console.log(err) });

console.log("123");
```

If I use testpromise(), And provide a "123"(reject) parameter.

This program was error.

Else, If I provide a "hello" parameter(resolve), Then it is correct.

Why is this happening?

## Last

Provide a "hello" parameter to this function:

```js
testpromise("hello", 3000)
    .then((res) => { console.log(res) })
    .catch((err) => { console.lof(err) });

console.log("123");
```

Then, Node return is correct.

**But**

`setTimeout()` Only results, no delay...

Intuitively speaking:

[image]

"123" before "hello", This is correct.

but no delay, no delay, no delay!!!

Why?

Help me, Please!

Thank you very much.

Comment: Typo: `console.lof` is not a function. I think in your error written exactly this

Comment: And your second question: no delay because you wrap in setTimepout only `resolve`, but `reject` you call instantly after check condition.

And `resolve` you call instantly too, cause you send *result* of calling function `resolve` as setTimeout callback, not the function itself

Comment: So, What should I do?

Comment: Supplement: `reject` indeed no delay is set. But "resolve" is set, no delay too?

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(()=>resolve(data), ms);
```

you must pass the function into setTimeout,  but not the result of the function

Comment: ```
setTimeout(()=>resolve(data), ms);
```
you must pass the function into setTimeout,  but not the result of the function

Comment: This is useless!

Comment: Arrow function is function, too.

Comment: ```()=>resolve(data)``` - it is a function.   
But ```resolve(data)``` - it is a result of the function